# GWT CSS DataGrid Hidden Button

Tags: css, button, gwt, datagrid

I've got a DataGrid on my GWT project. I do want add one or two buttons every grid line with hint. But when I've hover of the line they will visible, otherwise none visible. How can I do that? Like yahoo mail lines.

Test Line1 blah blah blah
Test Line1 blah blah blah

if I hoover first line it can be
Test Line1 blah bla[button1] [button2]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Add an image to your grid, and then set the following CSS style on the grid or the column where you want this effect:

```
.imageHover tr img {
    display: none;
}
.imageHover tr:hover img {
    display: block;
}
```